# SKSpriteNode not removing

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, sprite

**Edit**

So basically, every touch, I call this function:

```
[self AddSprite];
```

Now that code runs this method which basically creates a sprite on the screen. (I have declared things like `location` in code not shown).

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sprite.png"];
sprite.name = @"sprite";



sprite.xScale = Width;
sprite.yScale = Hight;



sprite.position = location;

[self addChild:sprite];
```

Then once another method is called, that contains:

```
[_sprite removeFromParent];
```

That is basically all the code to do with the area not working.
I do not know why the sprite is not being removed.

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: Please show more code: the declarations, when you add it etc. there's no enough to go on here.

Comment: You aren't assigning the sprite you created to the property `_sprite`. Try adding `self.sprite = sprite;` after the `[self addChild:sprite];` statement. You should now be able to remove it from its parent with `[_sprite removeFromParent];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not show us the code, **try:**

```
_sprite = nil;
[_sprite removeFromParent];
```

**Edit:**

Now when you edited the code I also see that you declare ivar `SKSpriteNode *sprite` but you are removing the property `_sprite`. Try `[sprite removeFromParent];`

Comment: It just ignores it again. Is there any code I could put on that could help?

Comment: If you put your node into a scene (like `[self addChild:_sprite]`) and you remove it, there should be no node. Maybe you recreating it elsewhere or removing the wrong one. What about `[self.sprite removeFromParent]`.

Comment: Ahh I see. I will check and get back to you soon. I would upvote you if I could for all that you have done :)

Comment: I have put on node count and it says there are only 2 nodes on the screen (The label and the sprite)

Comment: Is there a way you can just remove all nodes from the screen?

Comment: `[self removeAllChildren];`

Comment: Thanks! I just did self removeAllChildren above the bit where I add a label and it works! Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Since the OP did not post whole code I was trying to figure it out. If you would read my edit, you would see that I told him that he mashup ivar and property. Also thanks for downvote sir.